# SSIS Expression for data validation check on Column

Tags: ssis

Trying to build an expression or condition in SSIS for data validation.
For Instance one of the column should have Integers only and i need to check for that.
i need to check another column for decimals only. 
**In short: How would i build an expression/Condition for checking Intergers or Decimals.**

Comment: try this http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.de/2011/04/isnumeric-or-isnumber-expression-is.html

Comment: It needs to be done in Expression builder or Condition.